# angular material: vertically arranging contents in a mat-grid-tile

Tags: angular, material-design

I am using angular material and have a grid list component with two tiles. the problem is the contents are getting arranged left to right rather top to bottom.

```html
<mat-grid-list cols="3" style="padding:10px">
  <mat-grid-tile colspan="1" class="mi-tile-contents-top">
    <h2 class="mi-text-header">Title</h2>
    <div>some sort of text in between</div>
    <button mat-raised-button class="mi-button">Learn More</button>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile colspan="2"><img src="../assets/images/cg_app.png" width="100%"/></mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

i thought `div` should force the contents go vertically arranged but it doesnt.

Also by default the contents are arranged vertically align centered. trying `align-start` did not help in that either.

Seems basic thing to be working so not sure if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: did u tried changing colspan to 3? on both <mat-grid

Comment: and making mat-grid-list col span 6 ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason it's horizontal is because the Material lib is wrapping your tags located inside `mat-grid-tile` in a `flex` styled element that has a row [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) by default.

If I get it right, the code below should do want you want.
When using `grid-list` elements, the order has an importance

```html
<mat-grid-list cols="3" style="padding:10px">
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="1" rowspan="1">
        <h2>Title</h2>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="2" rowspan="3">
        <img src="../assets/images/cg_app.png" width="100%"/>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="1" rowspan="1">
      <div>some sort of text in between</div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="1" rowspan="1">
      <button mat-raised-button class="mi-button">Learn More</button>
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

You could also wrap the content of your `mat-grid-tile` in a div:

```html
<mat-grid-list cols="3" style="padding:10px">
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="2" >
        <div>
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <div>some sort of text in between</div>
            <button mat-raised-button class="mi-button">Learn More</button>
        </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="1">
        <img src="../assets/images/cg_app.png" width="100%"/>
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: is there a way to change the flex-direction

Comment: Better is create a separate component and add that inside the tile

Answer (score 1):

try below one, you have set colspan so that it will occupy full width of the div

```html
<mat-grid-list cols="3" style="padding:10px">
<mat-grid-tile md-colspan="6" colspan="6" class="mi-tile-contents-top">
  <h2 class="mi-text-header">Title</h2>
  <div>some sort of text in between</div>
  <button mat-raised-button class="mi-button">Learn More</button>
 </mat-grid-tile>
<mat-grid-tile md-colspan="6" colspan="6" ><img src="../assets/images/cg_app.png" width="100%"/></mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: what col span has to do with the contents inside the tile?

Comment: you have to use some css, try to pase your page html here so that we cna help better

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution that worked for me was to add the following to the *src/styles.css* file:

```
.mat-grid-tile-content
{
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Keep in mind this will be applied for the whole application.