# Angular material grid-list arrange content to go to top

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using the `mat-grid-list` to display some data

The content of the `grid-list-tile` is always centered in the middle of the tile.

How to make it go under the header instead of the middle?

I tried `top:10px` but no luck

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2">
  <mat-grid-tile
      [colspan]="1"
      [rowspan]="1">
      <mat-grid-tile-header>Title</mat-grid-tile-header>
    <p>Segment 1</p>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile
      [colspan]="1"
      [rowspan]="2">
      <mat-grid-tile-header>Title</mat-grid-tile-header>
         <p>Segment 2</p>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile
      [colspan]="1"
      [rowspan]="1">
      <mat-grid-tile-header>Title</mat-grid-tile-header>
    <p>Segment 3</p>
  </mat-grid-tile>  
</mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: You should see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46968990/angular-material-vertically-arranging-contents-in-a-mat-grid-tile

Comment: You should see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46968990/angular-material-vertically-arranging-contents-in-a-mat-grid-tile

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,its not best solution,but i can only managed to move text if i give it absolute position,maybe from this you can find what u need to work for your content.

```
  ::ng-deep mat-grid-tile p {
     position: absolute;
     top: 40px;
  }
```

Hope it was helpful.