# Stacking mat-checkboxes vertically within a mat-grid-list's mat-grid-tile component

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am wanting to have a grid list with 2 columns and in those columns I am wanting 2 checkboxes that are stacked vertically.

I have seen **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46968990/angular-material-vertically-arranging-contents-in-a-mat-grid-tile)** which does *somewhat* work, but I am wondering if there is a cleaner way around this, as I am having to use a considerable amount of `div`s to get this done....

**How I have it working at the moment**

```
<mat-grid-list cols=3 rowHeight="50px">
   <mat-grid-tile class="tile">
       <div>
          <div>
            <mat-checkbox>One</mat-checkbox>
          </div>
          <div>
            <mat-checkbox>Two</mat-checkbox>
          </div>
      </div>
   </mat-grid-tile>
   ...
<mat-grid-list>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a flexbox layout to the outer DIV and get rid of the inner DIVs:

```
<mat-grid-tile>
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
    <mat-checkbox>One</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox>Two</mat-checkbox>
  </div>
</mat-grid-tile>
```